# How can I bulk insert to MS-Access table using C# from gridview control?

Tags: c#, ms-access, gridview

I have tried to bulk insert data from datagrid control of C# to MS-Access database file. I wrote code as following:

```
  OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\\SoftwareModule\\insurance.mdb;");
        try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                comm.Connection = myConnection;
                myConnection.Open();
                int rowsCount = dbChequeGrid.Rows.Count;
                int rowsInserted = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
                {
                    string StrQuery = "INSERT INTO cust (clientname,clientaddress,clientfathername)VALUES (@id,@CourseName,@Credits)";
                    comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credits", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

                    if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        rowsInserted++;
                    }
                    comm.Parameters.Clear();
                }//end of for loop


                if (rowsCount == rowsInserted)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("All Rows Inserted Successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("All Rows Not Inserted Successfully!");
                }
            }

        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
        }
```

But Every time i run this code, I get the Following Error.

> Parameter "@someparameter" has no default value.

I surfed up many sites but didn't found what's wrong with my code.

Comment: is "Parameter "someparameter" has no default value." the actual text from the exception, or is someparameter one of the parameters listed in your insert statement (id, CourseName or Credits)?

Comment: I have inserted @id as my parameter. The actual exception is as follows.."Parameter id has no default value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value is null, and since there is no default value it is blowing up.

something like

```
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value==null?"somedfaultvalue":dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
```

should do the trick for you.  You could also do some error checking before doing the insert.  Something like

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                if(dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null){
                    string StrQuery = "INSERT INTO cust (clientname,clientaddress,clientfathername)VALUES (@id,@CourseName,@Credits)";
                    comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credits", dbChequeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

                    if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        rowsInserted++;
                    }
                    comm.Parameters.Clear();
                }else{
                     //do some sort of error handling
                }
            }//end of for loop
```

Either way would prevent NULLs from ever showing up in your @id parameter. I would check all of your parameters to see if they are correct before ever attempting to insert them into the database.